# Get UISwitch state into UIcollectionView at indexPath

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell, uiswitch

I display a list of users through a UICollectionView (stored in CoreData)
Each cell has :
- a name (UItextField)
- a state (ON / OFF) (bool)

I want to pass my boolean var concerning the user state (ON or OFF) with a UISwitch.

I've correctly set up my collectionview func :
identified my cell, displayed the name of user, added a target func for the UISwitch.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: userId, for: indexPath) as! UserCell
    let nameInfos = usersList[indexPath.item]
    cell.usersList = nameInfos
    nameInfos.name = cell.userNameTextField.text
    cell.userNameTextField.delegate = self
    let switchActive = cell.userSwitch

    switchActive.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.didPlayerActivate(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

    return cell
}

@objc func didPlayerActivate(_ sender : UISwitch){
    sender.isOn ? isActive() : isntActive()
}

// then my 2 func : isActive and isntActive
```

My question is how to set each user ON or OFF with my "didPlayerActivate" func.
I thought about selecting the right indexPath with the UISwitch, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Here’s the same issue with buttons instead of switches https://stackoverflow.com/q/28659845/1630618

Comment: In particular, [Paulw11’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38941510/1630618) is a clean way to handle it.

Comment: Thanks @vacawama, I thought about this solution I've seen before. But, for the moment, it just crashs my app :
`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: [MyApp.MySwitch _layoutAttributes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc6b1ebba00'`

Comment: The delegate method seems to be a good solution, but still impossible to reach indexPath : each time I try to guard let my indexPath, it crashes, even when I return nil...

Comment: Finally, I used closures and it works fine !
Protocol / delegate is not made for UISwitch.
Anyway @vacawama, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT :**
it seems that protocol and delegate method is not made for UISwitch, as said @Daniel here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32587078/8162027.
I succeeded with using closure like this :
in my cell :

```
var mySwitchAction : (()->())?
@objc func switchValueChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    self.switchAction?()
}
mySwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)
```

in my CollectionView :

```
cell.switchAction = {
        () in
        print("it works")
    }
```