# Switch location source from GPS to local `gpx` file

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, gpx

I want to have a switch that applies the location in the `sample-gpx.gpx` file to my application when toggled on, and do nothing when un-toggled.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var locationOnOff: UISwitch!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding listening to switch status:

1. Listen to the UISwitch value change event, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32587078/6426085)
2. In the valueChanged function, check the value of the switch by calling yourUISwitch.isOn

Regarding using `gpx` file (outside the simulator):

Are you fetching the location by using CLLocationManager? If so, in the CLLocation delegate call `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)`, you can check the switch isOn value and directly return the location specified in the `.gpx` file if it is toggled on.

I do not think there is a way for CLLocationManager to take your `.gpx` file directly. But perhaps a library like [this](https://github.com/vermont42/GpxLocationManager) will help?

Follow up if you have questions about this answer.